# Celery is it possible to make performance-intensive tasks on another computer without copying the source code?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Good day!

I want to ask about Celery. I have a project, and have are 3 tasks (run via cron, management commands). These tasks are very resource intensive and highly loaded server web server.

I want that these tasks are carried out on another computer (there is a separate server) and the result went into the main database.

I can do this by copying the entire project to another server, do not run there website, and run only the tasks (via cron). But it's not very good because I will have two identical copies of the source code. And if I will change it, I need to fill code in the web server and then copy it to a server that allocated to resource-intensive tasks ... Do not feel like ..

Can I do this with Celery? Ie project to be one copy, but my tasks on another server? Or I'll still will have to copy all the files to the server which will execute these commands?

Thank you.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery won't solve your "problem" of having 2 copies of the source code.

I would advise you that this is not a *problem* though. If you're worried about keeping the two servers in sync (in terms of deployment), try taking a look at [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.0/index.html) or other deployment tools.